# Extract 4 digit number from a text

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

```
    preg_match_all('/([\d]+)/', $text, $matches);

    foreach($matches as $match)
    {
        if(length($match) == 4){
            return $match;
        }
    }
```

i want use preg_match_all to extract only four digit number?

and if i want to get four digit or two digit number? (second case)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use

```
preg_match_all('/(\d{4})/', $text, $matches);
return $matches;
```

No need to use a character class if you only have `\d` to match, by the way (I omitted the square braces).

If you want to match either 4-digit or 2-digit numbers, use

```
preg_match_all('/(?<!\d)(\d{4}|\d{2})(?!\d)/', $text, $matches);
return $matches;
```

Here I employ negative lookbehind `(?<!\d)` and negative lookahead `(?!\d)` to prevent matching 2-digit parts of 3-digit numbers (e.g. prevent matching `123` as `12`).

Answer (score 3):

To match all the `4` digit number you can use the regex `\d{4}`

```
preg_match_all('/\b(\d{4})\b/', $text, $matches);
```

Next to match either `2` or `4` digit number you can use the regex `\d{2}|\d{4}` or a shorter regex `\d{2}(\d{2})?`

```
preg_match_all('/\b(\d{2}(\d{2})?)\b/', $text, $matches);
```

[**See it**](http://www.ideone.com/dwssK)

Answer (score 1):

Specify range `{4}` like this:

```
preg_match_all('/(\d{4})/', $text, $matches);
```

For two digits:

```
preg_match_all('/(\d{2})/', $text, $matches);
```

Comment: @BoltClock: Updated before seeing your comment :)